# While loop not correctly stopping as it should

Tags: python

I am writing a little program that is intended to draw a line 25 pixels wherever the randrange will give it it's points. I also have 4 red boxes that are acting as bombs or mines. When the x,y of the line is red by the getColor function, then the var 'color' will be == to red. Thus stopping the while loop, which will stop the line from continuing on. This is also the same desired function for the blue dots I have drawn on the playing field. I have found that my program is not functioning this way unfortunately.Any suggestions on how I could fix this?

```
 from random import *
 def main( ):
    #draw
    pic = makeEmptyPicture(600, 600, white)
    show(pic)

  #for the 4 boxes 
  boxCount = 0
  #while statement to draw
  while boxCount < 4:
       addRectFilled(pic, randrange(0,576), randrange(0,576), 25, 25, red)
       addArcFilled(pic, randrange(0,576), randrange(0,576), 10, 10, 0, 360, blue)
       boxCount = boxCount + 1
  repaint(pic)

  #vars for  while statement
  newX = 0
  newY = 0
  oldX = 0
  oldY = 0
  robotcount = 0
  finished = 0 
  safe = 0 
  triggered = 0
  #while loop, stops @ step 750, or when a px == red/blue
   while robotcount < 750 or color == red or color == blue:

         oldX = newX
         oldY = newY
         #how to generate a new line poing +25/-25
         newX = newX + randrange(-25, 26)
         newY = newY + randrange(-25, 26)
         #if statements to ensure no x or y goes over 599 or under 0
         if newX > 599 or newX < 0:
            newX = 0
         if newY > 599 or newY < 0:
            newY = 0
         #functions to get pixel color of x,y
         px = getPixel(pic, newX, newY)
         color = getColor(px)
         #draw the line from old to new, and also add +1 count for robot's steps
         addLine(pic, oldX, oldY, newX, newY, black)
         robotcount = robotcount + 1

  #if statement to determine why the while loop stops
  if color == red:
      triggered = 1
      printNow("trig")
  if color == blue:
      safe = 1
      printNow("safe")
  if robotcount == 750:
      finished = 1
      printNow("Fin")
```

Comment: How are `red` and `blue` defined?

Comment: Did you try to, you know, debug this problem yourself? I bet a little time with some printf debugging would do it.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Iguananaut more like where is `color` defined...

Comment: That too, but it must be defined somewhere otherwise they would get a `NameError`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pease take the time to read [ask].  Any chance you could condense the code in your question to a [mcve]?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: red and blue are already predefined in JES

Answer (score 0):

You would like to achieve this:

```
 #while loop, stops @ step 750, or when a px == red/blue
```

This does not work:

```
while robotcount < 750 or color == red or color == blue:
```

It would be simpler to use a `for`loop instead:

```
for robotcount in range(750):
    if color == red or color == blue:
        break
```

You can also use a `while` loop and fix your conditions (note the `!=`):

```
while robotcount < 750 or color != red or color != blue:
```

Comment: When the line is drawn through a red box, it still will not stop and output a different string per the last if then statement.

Comment: Also required to only use a while statement, not using for loops, yet.

Comment: Add an alternative with `while`.